# Converting COM object returned by IHTMLDocument2.Script.InvokeMember() to something useful

Tags: c#, .net, javascript, internet-explorer, pinvoke

I'm working with some code in C#.NET for an Internet Explorer extension that calls Javascript in the browser and gets the return value from the Javascript call.  When the Javascript returns a primitive type or an array of primitive types, I get something that I can deal with, but when the Javascript returns an object, I get an opaque COM object.

How can I get at the contents of the COM object, or is there a better way to call into IE from C#.NET?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the remarks at the bottom of the [InvokeMember documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/be9zzz62.aspx).  If the return value is a javascript object, you are receiving a .NET Object wrapper around the javascript object.  You will have to use reflection to inspect/invoke the members of the underlying javascript object.  This makes perfect sense, since javascript is a dynamic language and C# is not.